# Doubt in the derivation of the normal equation for minimizing cost function for regression

Tags: machine-learning

in the derivation given in this [**pdf**](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf), pages 10-11,
for the third step of the derivation the explanation given was that the trace of a real number is a real number. I dont understand how the whole equation inside the parathesis can be considered as a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta = [2 \, \, 4]^T$ and $\gamma = [1 \, \,2]^T$. Consider

$$ \mu = \theta^T\theta - \gamma^T\gamma\,. $$

$\theta^T \theta = 20$ is a scalar quantity, and $\gamma^T\gamma = 5$ is a scalar quantity. Thus the whole expression on the right hand side is a number, i.e.  $\mu = 25$ is a scalar. So
$$\mu = 25 = tr(25) = tr(\mu)\,. $$